# React Native project create and run error by react native CLI

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, npm

I am new in react native development. I am using new MacBook Air (M1, 2020) with M1 chip. I have installed:

```
Node version 14.15.3, 
Homebrew version 2.7.0, 
Xcode Version 12.3
```

When I am trying to create a new project by react native cli, then I am getting some error below:

```
sudo react-native init test
Password:
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test
Installing react-native...
Consider installing yarn to make this faster: https://yarnpkg.com
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN react-native@0.63.4 requires a peer of react@16.13.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN use-subscription@1.5.1 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ react-native@0.63.4
added 732 packages from 414 contributors and audited 732 packages in 310.649s

12 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
info Setting up new React Native app in /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test
(node:2294) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
info Adding required dependencies
+ react@16.13.1
added 1 package and audited 735 packages in 4.828s

12 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
info Adding required dev dependencies
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/object.values failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alimran/.npm/_logs/2020-12-25T16_12_07_249Z-debug.log
(node:2294) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: npm install --save-dev --save-exact @babel/core @babel/runtime @react-native-community/eslint-config eslint jest babel-jest metro-react-native-babel-preset react-test-renderer@16.13.1
    at makeError (/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async generateProject (/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/initCompat.js:128:3)
    at async Object.initCompat (/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/initCompat.js:105:3)
(node:2294) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:2294) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And when I am trying to run the app getting the error below:

```
react-native run-ios
warn Package @react-native-community/eslint-config has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module '@react-native-community/eslint-config/package.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/config/resolveNodeModuleDir.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/releaseChecker/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/start/runServer.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/start/start.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
warn Package babel-jest has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'babel-jest/package.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/config/resolveNodeModuleDir.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/releaseChecker/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/start/runServer.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/start/start.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
warn Package eslint has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'eslint/package.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/config/resolveNodeModuleDir.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/releaseChecker/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/start/runServer.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/start/start.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
warn Package jest has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'jest/package.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/config/resolveNodeModuleDir.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/releaseChecker/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/start/runServer.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/start/start.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
warn Package react-test-renderer has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'react-test-renderer/package.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/config/resolveNodeModuleDir.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/releaseChecker/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/start/runServer.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/start/start.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js
- /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
error Could not find "Podfile.lock" at /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/Podfile.lock. Did you run "pod install" in iOS directory?
info Found Xcode project "test.xcodeproj"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -project test.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme test -destination id=06B32499-BA8E-488E-B934-FDC4C7D2A385")
(node:2808) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening test.xcodeproj. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project test.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme test -destination id=06B32499-BA8E-488E-B934-FDC4C7D2A385

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the test editor. (in target 'test' from project 'test')
ProcessProductPackaging "" /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test.app.xcent (in target 'test' from project 'test')
    cd /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios
    

Entitlements:

{
    "com.apple.security.get-task-allow" = 1;
}


    builtin-productPackagingUtility -entitlements -format xml -o /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test.app.xcent

ProcessProductPackaging "" /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test.app-Simulated.xcent (in target 'test' from project 'test')
    cd /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios
    

Entitlements:

{
    "application-identifier" = "FAKETEAMID.org.reactjs.native.example.test";
    "keychain-access-groups" =     (
        "FAKETEAMID.org.reactjs.native.example.test"
    );
}


    builtin-productPackagingUtility -entitlements -format xml -o /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test.app-Simulated.xcent

PhaseScriptExecution Start\ Packager /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh (in target 'test' from project 'test')
    cd /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh
/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh: line 3: /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/../node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env: Permission denied

CompileC /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'test' from project 'test')
    cd /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DDEBUG\=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version\=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -index-store-path /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.dia -c /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.m -o /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
In file included from /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.m:1:
/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.h:1:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

CompileC /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/main.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'test' from project 'test')
    cd /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DDEBUG\=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version\=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -index-store-path /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.dia -c /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/main.m -o /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
In file included from /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/main.m:3:
/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.h:1:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/main.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
```

I hope some have the solution for this problem.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Updated question link: 

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458086/failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-with-erro) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a bunch of reasons why you're getting these errors.

1. First you should run *npx react-native run-ios* (and not just *react-native run-ios*)
2. If you're running an XCode project, run *pod install* in your ios directory before running react native
3. Your project workspace doesn't seem to find the node packages you have installed. If you're sure you've installed them, make sure you're running the command from the right directory (the one with your source folder)
4. Check your network connectivity. You might have a proxy configuration or firewall preventing you from downloading some packages.
5. It looks like the read/write rights to your folder aren't set properly, you might have to chmod a folder to make it read/writeable

To get more detailed help you'll have to provide information on your environment : react-native version, cli version, folder structure and possibly IDE (I see an eslint error in there...).

Comment: I have npm 6.14.9 and react-native-cli: 2.0.1. Please open the drive link for see the folder structure and react-native version into package.json file.
`https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1skmbi4nkMJqiSIbz-lFG4Frk4VwGh7SR?usp=sharing`